# Why is "arguments" a pseudo-array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Why is "arguments" a pseudo-array (array-like object) in JavaScript, but not just array? I think it happend historically, but what is the reason? Also why DOM-collections are pseudo-arrays. Does anybody know or at least have some guesses?

Comment: More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

If you need `arguments` as an array (for map(), etc.), it's easy enough to convert using the spread syntax:

```
let args = [...arguments];
```

Comment: I know. Also I can use `Array.from()` and `rest operator`, but my question about the reason. Why `arguments` is pseudo-array. It's more historical question, but I really interested in that.

Comment: @SergeiMartianov  Found an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242485/why-isnt-a-functions-arguments-object-an-array-in-javascript